# creating generic RESTful web service

Tags: java, rest

I have to create a RESTful web service. But, I was thinking for a generic RESTful web service for SOA. I don't know is it a good or bad idea for RESTful SOA.

How can I create generic web service which also satisfying REST concept.

Comment: what is generic webservice ? elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite an endeavour.
At a first thought you would have to provide some kind of abstraction layer over the resources that you would typically expose. And that's just the API. Then you would have to execute custom logic for every resource you access.

The short answer is that it's not worth trying to figure out. Going with the typical solutions we have now is far better than over-generalising REST.
There is no one-size-fits-all.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @Gabriel Ruiu - "There is no one-size-fits-all."

But if you are thinking about building an API kind of thing (maybe a library) using which one could build RESTful Services easily, then you can generalize some of things and expose the features via your API.